# Inline crud table in symfony3

Tags: symfony, crud

I'm starting to learn Symfony3 and i want to build a table where I can perform edit/delete and add actions but i don't know even where to start So if you can help me with anything it would be great.

Example of what I want to build

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your start should be the official documentation at https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Apart from that: Symfony provides a bundle called SensioGeneratorBundle, which is included in the default installation. It includes a crud generator.

Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also check more advance example of admin generator bundle: [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build it from scratch you will need to:

- Define your entities and use the CRUD command.
  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html
- Correctly define in the forms created the data type and properties you want to use in the form.
  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html
- Change the style in your views. If you use bootstrap you can install it with bower.